# How to install owping tool?

Tags: make, ping, configure

I would like to install owping, however I am not able to configure and compile sources. I have installed autoconf.

[Instructions to install owping](https://github.com/perfsonar/owamp/blob/master/INSTALL)

I have downloaded and unpacked sources of master branch.
Run command:

```
./configure
```

Gives 'No such file or directory'

In the Internet I found that following command may help.

```
autoreconf -i
```

However in the end I am not able to make and install this tool. It gives errors. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be some updates with `$ git submodule update --init` . And : The creation of the `configure` script is done most correctly with `bootstrap`.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/perfsonar/owamp.git
$ cd owamp/
$ git submodule update --init
$ ./bootstrap
$ ./configure
$ make            ## no errors here
```